# relative codebase field in applet in embedded system

Tags: java, html, applet, codebase

I was wondering if someone could provide me with some background of how exactly the codebase and code tags work when running a java applet.

My problem is this: I have a java applet which comprises of multiple class files over several directories (eg, I have main/applet.class, main/panel.class, geom/shapes.class...).  The applet works fine when run from my local hard drive, but now I want to move it to run off of an embedded system.  The files in my embedded system would look like this:

```
+ webs
| - appPage.html
|-+ myApp
  |-+ main
  |   - applet.class
  |   - panel.class
  |-+ geom
      - shapes.class
```

(It's actually quite a bit bigger than that...).  Given that I can load appPage.html from my browser, what would the code and codebase fields of the applet tag look like?  (I've tried several combinations, and haven't been able to find any that fit.  I keep getting message boxes such as

```
<applet code = "main/applet.class" codebase="webs/myApp" width=1000 height=700></applet>
```

but I get a ClassNotFoundException error (main.applet.class).  I've searched the web and cannot find a good explanation of exactly what codebase or code are supposed to refer to.  Any help would be appreciated (note: I'm new to java and html, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious).

Comment: Have you tried `codebase="myApp"`?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried several things, none of which worked.  I figured the web page was being loaded from a parent page which is in the parent directory, so perhaps the codebase had to be relative to the parent page instead of the current page, which was how I got to the example above -- of course that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the structure shown, this:

```html
<applet 
  code = "main/applet.class" 
  codebase="webs/myApp" 
  width=1000 
  height=700>
</applet>
```

Should be:

```html
<applet 
  code = "main.applet" 
  codebase="../myApp" 
  width=1000 
  height=700>
</applet>
```

Answer (score 1):

from [HTML applet Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp):

- codebase: Specifies a relative base URL for applets specified in the code attribute
- code: Specifies the file name of a Java applet
- archive: Specifies the location of an archive file

In other words:

`code` specifies what class in your JAR should be executed in order to start the Applet (this class should extend java.Applet or javax.swing.JApplet). In your case `main.applet.class`

`codebase` is the **relative** URL-path to your JAR-File.

you should also define the `archive` attribute in `<applet>` with `myApp.jar`

Comment: JAR file you say? (did I mention I was new to this?).  I can try to create a JAR file and use that instead of the .class files.  It would be neater.  For codebase you mention http://mywebserver/webs/ which would be absolute path.  In my case, because it's an embedded system, the absolute path would be dependent on the device's IP, so I would need to specify a relative path.  So, the path should be relative to what exactly (the path of the html page with the <applet> tag I presume?)

Comment: _the path of the html page with the <applet> tag_ **Yes**. and creating a jar is easy ;) google it

Comment: If I move the .jar file into the same directory as the html file, and omit the codebase field it works.  Outside of that, it doesn't seem to work.  The relative codebase seems to be killing me.  In any case, the jar file is sufficient for my needs as I'm not messing up my parent directory with tons new files.  Thanks